# How to block people on Gmail

Tags: gmail

How do I block people on Gmail?

Comment: Welcome to Web Applications. This question doesn't show any research effort. Please checkout [ask].

Comment: You can block someone on Hangouts, but I don't know if this would block them on Gmail as well. Also, this doesn't appear to be the best place to ask that question.

Answer (score 2):

From https://support.google.com/mail/answer/8151:

> ## **Block unwanted emails**
>
> If you’re getting emails you don’t want in your inbox, you can block the sender, unsubscribe from the sender, or report the message depending on the type of email.
> Emails from senders you block will be sent to your spam folder.

### To block a sender in GMail:

> 1. Open the email.
> 2. At the top right of the email, click the down arrow.
> 3. Click Block [sender].
>
> *If you blocked someone by mistake, you can unblock them using the same steps.*

[image: Blocking sender in GMail]